# Red and blue chameleon

Tags: meaning

I want to say there's a chameleon which is sometimes red and sometimes blue. I can express it as 'there's a chameleon sometimes red and sometimes blue,' but can I also express it as 'there's a red and blue chameleon'?

Comment: Your first sentence (including _which is_) is the best. _Red and blue_ implies that it is both colours at once.

Comment: You could also indicate that it's not red and blue at the same time by saying "there's a chameleon that changes between red and blue".

Answer (score 1):

"The chromatophores in this chameleon's skin can alternate between red and blue hues."

This gives the reader more information about the mechanism chameleons use to change colors, as well as indicating that the red and blue colors are not produced simultaneously.

Fascinating information here about [chromatophores](https://phys.org/news/2013-05-chameleons-creatures-colour.html) in frogs, lizards and fish (vertebrates) and in invertebrates like octopi, cuttlefish and other cephalopods.