# I move my hair back and forth

Tags: meaning

When it comes to 'I move my hair back and forth,' it doesn't mean 'I move my hair back and forth at the same time.'

Comment: *"it doesn't mean 'I move my hair back and forth at the same time.'* Why do you say this? I believe that it does mean that.  Who told you this was wrong and what was their explanation?

Comment: moving one's hair back and forth at the same time is possible?

Comment: Please explain what **you** mean by the two sentences. Here is someone swaying their hair https://media.tenor.com/images/d5746336c37618514a08b81ec10a8343/tenor.gif  Is this what you are referring to?

Comment: Yes I mean that

Comment: NOTE: I have just understood your question!

Comment: This is a duplicate of the question migrated from EL&U under a different account @chasly-supportsMonica An anonymous suggested edit tried to add this to that question. We should probably wait to answer until it gets sorted out. https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/274824/9161

Comment: @ColleenV  -  Thanks. I was already answering so I missed your comment until afterwards. I'll leave my answer for now and let the moderators sort it out!

Comment: Anything that is connected at one end to a base can be moved **back and forth**. It is not at the same time. It is first forth, then back. However, with one's hair (long hair), move is not the right verb. "She waved the flag back and forth from the window". You see? She jerked her head back and forth, hair flying.

Comment: She flung or whipped her head back and forth which caused her hair to balloon out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can move parts of one's body back and forth.

- She moved her fingers back and forth over the box. For example.
- He moved his feet back and forth over the mat. [He is sitting down]

As hair is attached to a head, the hair moves because the head moves.

Here is a video of a young girl **whipping her hair back and forth (because she is moving her head).**

If you move your head, the hair will move. However, hair is not like a detached object and cannot therefore be moved back and forth. Hair is also not like a limb (legs or arms) or hands or feet. These can be moved back and forth over something.

[whipping hair back and forth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bmaErg4FUAc)

There are many other ways to describe this movement of the hair, but, it must be the head that moves and the hair follows.

Answer (score 0):

> When it comes to 'I move my hair back and forth,' it doesn't mean 'I
> move my hair back and forth at the same time.'

(1) We can tell from the **context**. It is physically  impossible for something to move back and simultaneously to move forth.

(2) We can expand the sentence as follows:

*I move my hair back and then forth.*

Notice that "**back and forth**" is a fixed expression as are "up and down" and "side to side". They all specifically refer to [reciprocating motion](https://www.reference.com/science/examples-reciprocating-motion-c98adf2e6d423d2a).

---

P.S.

We can say the following:

*I am moving my hair back and to the side.*

The human expectation is that these two actions can happen simultaneously so that is how we usually interpret it.

Comment: So you mean I move my hair back and forth is semantically wrong?

Comment: @guestisalwaysright - No, it isn't wrong. It is semantically ambiguous. That is why AI has trouble understanding language. We humans know that certain things are possible in the real world so we do not need to have everything spelled out.  A robot might 'believe' that back and forth are possible at the same time. (I'll add something to my answer)

Comment: Then can I express blue then red lizard as blue red lizard?

Comment: "blue red" is not a fixed expression, "back and forth" is a fixed expression that implies movement. Could you ask a separate question and make it clear what the lizard looks like. Does it (a) change colour like a chameleon, or (b) does it have different (fixed) colours on different parts of its body?

Comment: it changes color. it's red after it's blue. so blue then red lizard blue red lizard

Comment: You can treat it as traffic light. blue then red light, blue red light

Comment: @Lambie - Maybe my imagination is better than yours but in my experience, young women with long hair often perform this sort of movement. In fact there is a song about it.  ["I whip my hair back and forth"](https://youtu.be/4Q97ilVo1T4?t=62)

Comment: *"I moved the chair back and forth in front of the stage."* Explain to me how one can do ***this***. The explanation is that you moved your *hands* back and forth and that caused the chair to move. It's an exact parallel.

Comment: No, it is not the same at all: You can *move an object back and forth*. Hair is attached to a head, ergo, you cannot move the hair unless your head moves. For the hair, some other verb besides move has to be used. The horse whipped its tail from side to side. The first whipped her hair back and forth.

Comment: Traffic light is red then blue = red then blue traffic light = red blue traffic light?

Comment: @Lambie - Okay I retract that accusation. My point is simple.  If I move my ears up and down, then I agree with you. Moving my head does not cause an independent movement of my ears. However if I cause my hair to move by shaking my head, the hair has its own movement. I move my hair by using my head as a tool, in the same way that I move a yoyo using my hand and the string as tools.

Comment: @guestisalwaysright - Please submit this as a separate question. It is not good to ask and answer questions in the comments. ;-)